Ask a question on short-run and long-run supply curve?
Question: True, False, Uncertain? [Explain your answer.] The price
of quinoa (an edible grain) has recently risen due to an unexpected, but permanent, increase
in demand. Nothing else changes in the economy. The change in quinoa demand will cause
the short-run supply curve for quinoa to shift outwards over time in response to the higher
quinoa prices, but will have no effect on the long-run supply curve of quinoa.
My answer is False. My idea is that in the short-run, it's not easy to have more firms enter in the market. So the short-run supply curve keeps same, though the equilibrium point changes. But in the long-run, more firms enter, so the long-run supply curve move right.
However, this is the official solution:
Solution: True. In the long run, more quinoa will be grown given the higher market price for quinoa.
This implies that the short-run supply curve shifts out as more “entry” occurs (i.e., more acres of
quinoa planted). The long-run supply curve already captures these expansion effects, so the long-run supply curve should not shift without additional exogenous variables impacting the supply side
of the market.
Do you agree this solution?

Yes, I agree. The economy is initially in equilibrium. There is a demand and there is a long-run and a short-run supply. A demand shock occurs and as a result, the price will increase to the equilibrium given by short-run supply and new demand. In the short run capital or the number of firms is fixed. Therefore, the short-run supply equilibrium price is higher than the long-run supply equilibrium price (short-run supply being less elastic). Over time more firms will enter or firms will invest in more capital shifting the short run curve outwards until short-run equilibrium is equal to long run
